# How do you get sum function working in SQLquery in RODBC

Tags: sql, r, hadoop, impala, rodbc

I have a script which works in as an SQL query in Hadoop Impala, however when I try to run in R using the package RODBC the only line creating an error if the "sum" function, as follows:

```
install.packages("RODBC")
library(RODBC)
conn <- odbcConnect("ODBC Impala")

example1 <- sqlQuery(conn, "
select
    column1 as Name, column2 as Date, sum(column3) as Balance
from 
    database1.table1
where 
    column2="20151130"")
```

However when i exclude:

```
sum(column3) as Balance
```

the script runs just fine. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Please specify your output needs: unit level, grouped level, or all groups level. Specifically, do you expect one sum value or multiple sum values for each `Name`, `Date`? As it stands your original query is syntactically incorrect in SQL as you combine an aggregate with unit levels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, you need a `group by`:

```
select column1 as Name, column2 as Date, sum(column3) as Balance
from  database1.table1
where column2 = '20151130'
group by column1, column2;
```

Comment: To explain further, in the original question, the SQL code was attempting to combine non aggregated and aggregated results, which it doesn't really like to do.  Adding the `group by` forces everything into an aggregated state.